# REST: addUsingPath not supported in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, 2016, pnpjs

I run this in the browser:

```
https://my.company.com/sites/news/_api/web/folders/addUsingPath(DecodedUrl='%2Fsites%2Fjnews%2Frufus%2Fholla',overwrite=false)
```

and get:

```
Cannot find resource for the request addUsingPath.
```

problem is that I use pnp/js version 3, which is using above. does this mean that if I still need to support 2016 I need to downgrade to version 2?

Answer: Yes, one needs to revert to version 2: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/2872#issuecomment-1866199076

Answer (score 0):

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/transition-guide/

You’ll need to use version 2 of the PnPjs library. Version 3 of PnPjs is only supported in SharePoint Framework (SPFx) v1.14 and higher and NodeJs v12.x and higher. Version 3 of the library only supports ESModules.